# React-native creates multiple rootView on Android

Tags: android, react-native

I'm using React-Native 0.53.0 now and the problem is that it creates multiple RootView so the app is getting slower because of the many RootView created.

I tested with the initial project created by the command "react-native init XX" on two different laptops and the behavior of it is still same.

I printed some logs in react-native android code to see why it happened, and here's what I found so far.

When I install the app for the first time and close the app then the app state becomes pause.

And I open the app again by pressing the app icon, ReactActivity.onCreate() gets called again even though the app is in the background. So another RootView gets created without detaching the previous one.

so the log printed is like below.

1. **ReactActivity.onCreate()** <- Start the app for the first time
2. **Running application "Lish" with appParams: {"rootTag":1}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF** <- RootView created
3. **ReactActivityDelegate.onPause()** <- Close the app and it is in the background
4. **ReactActivity.onCreate()** <- Open the app again by pressing the app icon and it is called again
5. **Running application "Lish" with appParams: {"rootTag":11}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF** <- Another RootView created again
6. **ReactActivityDelegate.onResume()** <- called

the following is the whole logs.

```
02-26 11:01:08.567 19203 19203 D ReactNative: ReactActivityDelegate.LoadApp
02-26 10:59:38.316 19203 19203 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.ctor()
02-26 10:59:38.357 19203 19203 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContextInBackground()
02-26 10:59:38.357 19203 19203 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackgroundInner()
02-26 10:59:38.366 19203 19203 D ReactNative: ReactActivityDelegate.onResume()
02-26 10:59:41.219 19203 19203 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.onJSBundleLoadedFromServer()
02-26 10:59:41.219 19203 19203 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackground()
02-26 10:59:41.219 19203 19203 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.runCreateReactContextOnNewThread()
02-26 10:59:41.233 19203 19239 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext()
02-26 10:59:41.290 19203 19239 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge.
02-26 10:59:41.294 19203 19239 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge before initializeBridge
02-26 10:59:41.315 19203 19239 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge after initializeBridge
02-26 10:59:41.315 19203 19239 D ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle()
02-26 10:59:41.318 19203 19242 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.setupReactContext()
02-26 10:59:41.318 19203 19242 D ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.initialize()
02-26 10:59:41.320 19203 19242 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.attachRootViewToInstance()
02-26 10:59:43.185 19203 19241 I ReactNativeJS: Running application "Lish" with appParams: {"rootTag":1}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF
02-26 11:00:33.905 19203 19203 D ReactNative: ReactActivityDelegate.onPause()
02-26 11:00:49.536 19203 19203 D ReactNative: ReactActivity.onCreate()
02-26 11:00:49.536 19203 19203 D ReactNative: ReactActivityDelegate.LoadApp()
02-26 11:00:49.536 19203 19203 D ReactNative: LoadApp
02-26 11:00:49.538 19203 19203 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.attachRootViewToInstance()
02-26 11:00:49.546 19203 19203 D ReactNative: ReactActivityDelegate.onResume()
02-26 11:00:50.445 19203 19241 I ReactNativeJS: Running application "Lish" with appParams: {"rootTag":11}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF
02-26 11:01:06.466 19203 19203 D ReactNative: ReactActivityDelegate.onPause()
02-26 11:01:08.567 19203 19203 D ReactNative: ReactActivity.onCreate
02-26 11:01:08.567 19203 19203 D ReactNative: ReactActivityDelegate.LoadApp
02-26 11:01:08.568 19203 19203 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.attachRootViewToInstance()
02-26 11:01:08.575 19203 19203 D ReactNative: ReactActivityDelegate.onResume()
02-26 11:01:13.755 19203 19241 I ReactNativeJS: Running application "Lish" with appParams: {"rootTag":21}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF
```

So another RootView gets created as many as I close and open the app.

But when I close the app and open it again by pressing it on Overview screen, it works fine. ReactActivity.onCreate() doesn't get called again.

so the log is like below.

1. **ReactActivity.onCreate()** <- Start the app for the first time
2. **Running application "Lish" with appParams: {"rootTag":1}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF** <- RootView created
3. **ReactActivityDelegate.onPause()** <- Close the app and it is in the background
4. **ReactActivityDelegate.onResume()** <- Open the app again by pressing the app screen on Overview screen

the following is the whole logs.

```
02-26 11:02:12.532 19393 19393 D ReactNative: ReactActivity.onCreate
02-26 11:02:12.532 19393 19393 D ReactNative: ReactActivityDelegate.LoadApp
02-26 11:02:12.532 19393 19393 D ReactNative: LoadApp
02-26 11:02:12.537 19393 19393 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.ctor()
02-26 11:02:12.593 19393 19393 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContextInBackground()
02-26 11:02:12.593 19393 19393 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackgroundInner()
02-26 11:02:12.594 19393 19393 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.onJSBundleLoadedFromServer()
02-26 11:02:12.595 19393 19393 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackground()
02-26 11:02:12.595 19393 19393 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.runCreateReactContextOnNewThread()
02-26 11:02:12.630 19393 19393 D ReactNative: ReactActivityDelegate.onResume()
02-26 11:02:12.642 19393 19413 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext()
02-26 11:02:12.781 19393 19413 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge.
02-26 11:02:12.786 19393 19413 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge before initializeBridge
02-26 11:02:12.796 19393 19413 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge after initializeBridge
02-26 11:02:12.797 19393 19413 D ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle()
02-26 11:02:12.798 19393 19421 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.setupReactContext()
02-26 11:02:12.798 19393 19421 D ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.initialize()
02-26 11:02:12.803 19393 19421 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.attachRootViewToInstance()
02-26 11:02:14.801 19393 19420 I ReactNativeJS: Running application "Lish" with appParams: {"rootTag":1}. __DEV__ ===     true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF
02-26 11:02:18.928 19393 19393 D ReactNative: ReactActivityDelegate.onPause()
02-26 11:02:24.118 19393 19393 D ReactNative: ReactActivityDelegate.onResume()
02-26 11:02:26.129 19393 19393 D ReactNative: ReactActivityDelegate.onPause()
02-26 11:02:28.815 19393 19393 D ReactNative: ReactActivityDelegate.onResume()
02-26 11:02:30.567 19393 19393 D ReactNative: ReactActivityDelegate.onPause()
02-26 11:02:34.610 19393 19393 D ReactNative: ReactActivityDelegate.onResume()
```

and it only happens when the app is installed for the first time. if I completely close the app even from background and open again then it never happens whether I open it by pressing the app icon or by pressing the app screen on Overview.

Below is the link of the video that I made showing how it happened.

https://youtu.be/XatU7vQBcdA

I think it's a really serious issue for Android. I already posted an issue on React-Native github several days ago, but there's no response yet.

Could somebody look into it and help me on this issue please? :)

Comment: I solved it by adding android:launchMode="singleTop" in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Can you share the Github issue so others can track it as well? Thanks!